# Why public domain is need to configure SharePoint Hybrid and why *.sharepoint.com is not enough

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, 2016, hybrid-solution

I read different articles on how to configure Hybrid Search, Delve etc. in SharePoint and came to know that you need to have a domain for SharePoint Hybrid to work.

As far as I understand a domain is needed because on-premise SharePoint cannot be accessed from outside from Office 365 so we will need to buy a domain and map it to on-premise SharePoint server so for e.g. it will become `http://mysharepoint.company.com`

But I get the impression from articles that domain is needed at Office 365 end and this is where it will be configured so I am confused about why it is needed? Why my tenant for e.g. `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com` won't work in Hybrid.

Another question, if I am just configuring Cloud Hybrid Search, even then I need a domain to be configured in Office 365?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You need a domain for O365, yes. You also need _something_ for your on-prem farm.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So it means two domains are needed one for O365 for e.g. myonline.company.com and one for on-premise for e.g. mypremise.company.com?

Comment: You only need one. On-prem would use https://mypremesis.company.com and online would be https://mypremesis.sharepoint.com.

Comment: Please check screenshot I have posted in my edit above. It is talking about registering a domain with O365.

Comment: Correct, you need to register a public domain. Follow the instructions in the O365 Setup or ask here if they're unclear.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this the same on-premises public domain that will be registered with O365?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but in your scenario probably.